# Running Python27 interpreter in bash shell on win7

Tags: bash, shell

Added to ~/.bash_profile

```
PATH=c:/Python27:$PATH
```

and

```
env | grep PATH
```

shows the path c:/Python27

However I cannot run python interpreter from command line in bash.  I'm on Windows 7 and I can run python from any directory in command prompt after doing

```
path %path%;C:\Python
```

Or adding the path to my Environment Variables

In bash I am able to do other commands from any directory in terminal after adding their path to ~/.bash_profile given the path is a sub-directory of ~/

If the path in .bash_profile is C:/ rather than ~/ it doesn't work. So my question is when adding a path to .bash_profile where the location is in C:/ rather than ~/ how do i do it?

Comment: Is the interpreter in C:\Python27 or in C:\Python, as your cmd example suggests?

Comment: C:\Python27 I was being dumb :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash uses `:` as the path separator, so you actually just added "c" and "/Python27" to your PATH.

Different Windows GNU toolset ports have different ways of working around this. You can try `ls /c/`, `ls /cygdrive/c` or read your port's documentation to see how it handles this.

If you find that e.g. `/c/Python27` is mapped to c:\Python27, then you can add that to your path instead.

Comment: Thanks I should've known.  Brain fart.